# gTTS will not install, shows up as UNKNOWN

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gtts

I have tried in vain to get gTTS working on my win10 machine.

I have upgraded pip.
i have run `pip install gtts` but all it installs is something called UNKNOWN

`pip list` gives me:

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
aiohttp       1.0.5
async-timeout 3.0.1
asyncio       3.4.3
cffi          1.12.2
chardet       3.0.4
discord       0.16.12
discord.py    0.16.12
multidict     4.5.2
pip           19.0.3
pycparser     2.19
PyNaCl        1.3.0
pyttsx        1.1
setuptools    28.8.0
six           1.12.0
UNKNOWN       2.0.3
websockets    3.4
```

notice the UNKNOWN where my GTTS should be?

when i try install, i get this:

```
Collecting gTTS
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/37/f55346a736278f0eb0ae9f7edee1a61028735ef0010db68a2e6fcd0ece56/gTTS-2.0.3.tar.gz
  Generating metadata for package gTTS produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=gTTS fragments.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unknown from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/37/f55346a736278f0eb0ae9f7edee1a61028735ef0010db68a2e6fcd0ece56/gTTS-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=a6d4cf039da2797de8af2da7c1f0ce700ac0b48601ce6c11a02b337fd6bdcf57 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

And i cant call gTTS through `from gtts import gTTS` it just crashes my program every time.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/159

Comment: https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/158

Answer (score -1):

## Use "pip install --upgrade gTTS"

So it looks like python generating metadata package for Googles Text-to-Speech gTTS. You now have use "--upgrade" to put the gTTS fragments of your first attempt at downloading gTTS together. You do this by calling:
 "pip install --upgrade gTTS"

Hope this helps.

---